What could I have done to make thin grey lines invisible?
For example, no gridlines in google calendar:

The only time I see them, when I have this overlay open. Any setting changes nothing however:

No grey lines at all:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
When I change the settings I do see some grey lines, but only here.
Example, allow tinting gives some grey lines:
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
Im not sure what I did but I can't remember this ever been a problem. What should I change how? Dark theme doesn't do much.
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/9QNs5trK.png
[4]: https://i.sstatic.net/fz9FECf6.png

Hi, a couple clarifications and a request. Request to edit your image links. If you use the built in image controls, markdown format should work better. 1. What version of macOS? 2. Do you intentionally choose a color correction (night shift, manual calibration)? 3. On which screens are you looking at the content?
